# irrespective of the values, the if block is executing in C#

Tags: c#-3.0

```
if (updateYN.ToUpper() != Constants.NO
                        || updateYN.ToUpper() != Constants.N)
{
  // execute code for any other updateYN
}
```

I am trying to perform a filtration that if the value of updateYN is not NO(Constants.NO) or N(Constants.N), then execute the statement.

But the problem is that, irrespective of the values, the if block is executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want an AND statement...no? (NOT NO AND NOT N)

Answer (score 1):

OK, your problem is you are translating language to code. Your statement should be:

```
if (updateYN.ToUpper() != Constants.NO
                        && updateYN.ToUpper() != Constants.N)
{
  // execute code for any other updateYN
}
```

This tells the compiler that updateYN.ToUpper() should not be NO and should not be N.

**EDIT**: To make it more clear why your if condition is always getting concluded, here is some explanation. Imagine this statement:

if (x != 1 || x != 2)
{
   ...
}

You would imagine that if x is 1 or 2, the block shouldn't be executed, but it WILL, because this statement consists of two parts actually:

x != 1
x != 2

The or part tells the compiler that if any of these conditions is true, then the whole condition is true. Obviously, if x is 1, then it is not 2, so the condition is fulfilled, and same thing if it is 2. Think of all the values in the world, they can't be equal to 1 and 2, so this block will always get executed. Same with your case here. Hope that explains your problem well.

Answer (score 1):

Logically think about it this way:
your statement breaks down into three components

```
a = updateYN.ToUpper() != Constants.NO
b = updateYN.ToUpper() != Constants.N

c = a or b
```

But if you think about it, if  `updateYN.ToUpper()` is `Constants.NO` then a is false, but b is true, and thus c is true.  And if  `updateYN.ToUpper()` is `Constants.N` then b is false, but a is true, and thus c is true.   What you seem to want is

```
if(updateYN.ToUpper() != Constants.NO && updateYN.ToUpper() != Constants.N)
```

This means that `updateYN.ToUpper()` must equal something other than `Constants.NO` and `Constants.N` in order for the entire statement to be true.

Answer (score 0):

If `Constants.NO` and `Constants.N` are not equal, this is always `true`. It is probably always different from either `NO` or `N`.